# How to install and migrate to High Sierra on an encrypted FS?

Tags: install, high-sierra, encryption, migration, apfs

[ I am in the process of migrating an old MacBook Pro to a new one. ]

I made a complete 8 GB USB "`Install macOS High Sierra`".
I checked it (`Disk Utility`) from my running old MacBook Pro.

I booted from this USB key on my new MacBook Pro not connected to anything (no Wi-Fi neighbour, no Internet) so as to make a secure and clean initial installation. I proceeded through the following steps:

1. `Disk Utility`: I formatted the internal SSD as APFS encrypted case sensitive, and gave the partition a solid password: "`password_SSD`".
2. `Install MacOS`: I selected the just created APFS encrypted case sensitive partition. I entered its password: "`password_SSD`".
3. The installer rebooted, I entered "`password_SSD`".
4. The installer asked me if I wanted to migrate information from another Mac, TM or external disk. I chose an external disk containing my previous MacBook Pro running High Sierra on HFS+ case sensitive (not encrypted).
5. I selected to migrate everything.
6. The installer asked me to choose an admin account. I selected my previous admin account `Bob`, entered a new solid password: "`password_admin`". Then I was asked to enter the partition password so that the selected admin could open the encrypted partition: "`password_SSD`".
7. The installation process proceeded quietly for 4 hours, and displayed me the following error window **error n°1**:

   ```
   Sorry
   An error occured while transferring your information.

   ! Bob could not be created.
   ```

   But nonetheless proposed me a `Continue` button. I chose this continue option after so much wasted time (why not to check if I can exit alive from a few hours tunnel).
8. MacOS High Sierra finally booted and asked me the SSD password: "`password_SSD`".
9. The Login Window proposed me to choose from my known users accont plus a great number of daemon accounts: **error n°2**.
10. I selected `Bob` and `password_admin`. My session opened but any Finder selection gave an error popup window **error n°3**: `"file" can't be opened because the original item can't be found.`

It is clear that this installation didn't run correctly. And I searched through the `/var/log/install.log` which had been filled, but didn't find any intelligent explanation about the size of damage of **error n°1**.

I tried a slightly different procedure with an external disk and a partition of HFS+ case sensitive (after a full erase of course). The process terminated completely without any of the above 3 errors. 2 differences: APFS / HFS+, encrypted / not encrypted.

I tried another different procedure with the internal SSD and a partition
of HFS+ case sensitive. The process produced the same 3 errors as in the
initial case.

The problem seems to be around "encrypted" **and** "migrate".

---

This is the reason I ask here this question before wasting another chunk of 5 hours.

How to install and migrate to High Sierra on an encrypted FS?

Did I made a big error in my procedure?

Is this a known problem?

How may I further analyze this problem to eventually help to fix it?

Comment: @klanomath: danke :).